# BIND - why duplicate nameserver entries (@ and *)?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I had to manually tweak my DNS service providers BIND file.

**BIND file, created by professional hosting company, before:**

```
$ORIGIN mycoolsite.com.  
$TTL 300  
@ SOA ns1.cheapreg.com. registry.cheapreg.com. ( ... )  
@ IN 3600 NS ns1.cheapreg.com.  
@ IN 3600 NS ns2.cheapreg.com.  
@ IN 3600 A 199.9.99.85  
@ IN 3600 A 199.9.99.86  
* IN 3600 A 199.9.99.85  
* IN 3600 A 199.9.99.86  
www IN 3600 A 199.9.99.85    
www IN 3600 A 199.9.99.86
```

**BIND file, created by layman, after:**

```
$ORIGIN mycoolsite.com.  
$TTL 300
@ SOA ns1.cheapreg.com. registry.cheapreg.com. ( ... )  
@ IN 3600 NS ns1.cheapreg.com.  
@ IN 3600 NS ns2.cheapreg.com.  
* IN 3600 A 219.94.116.50  
* IN 3600 A 219.94.116.51  
* IN 3600 A 219.94.116.52
```

The difference is that the "pro"-file has duplicated the nameserver entries, once for @, and once for *,
and I haven't.

**Any reason I should also duplicate nameserver entries (@ and *) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the first bind file, I believe the following will send out both of the IPs when you query mycoolsite.com for its A record:

```
@ IN 3600 A 199.9.99.85
@ IN 3600 A 199.9.99.86
```

The following records are wildcard records:

```
* IN 3600 A 199.9.99.85
* IN 3600 A 199.9.99.86
```

so when you query `couldthispossiblyexist.mycoolsite.com` or `blah1290eu.mycoolsite.com` for A records, you will receive both IPs.

Comment: This doesn't *really* answer the question though...

Answer (score 3):

`@` represents records for the main domain itself (i.e. without any prefixes)

`*` is a wildcard record, representing all possible *sub-domains* of the main domain, but not the domain itself.

Hence in this case your new zone file won't supply any "A records" (i.e. IP addresses) when queried for the domain itself, but only for its subdomains.

[You say that it's the nameserver entries that are duplicated but that's not the case - it's clearly the lines with `A` rather than `NS` that were duplicated but now aren't]

Answer (score 1):

There are two main differences:

- The first example explicitly duplicates the `A` entry for the subdomain `www`, even though they would otherwise be covered by the `*` (wildcard) subdomain `A` entry.  This should not affect the result given for lookups of the `www` subdomain at all.

  It is there only for the benefit of whoever is maintaining the zone file: to inform them that `www` is actually used.  It is often preferable to list the actual subdomain names that you're using rather than use wildcards only, because it helps serve as a self-reminder to whoever might be managing that zone in the future, about which subdomains are actually being used.  This may be helpful should you want to migrate one day.

  As for whether you should do it - it's not mandatory.
- The second example removes the `A` record for the domain itself.

  This is a problem, because it means that `mycoolsite.com` alone (without any subdomain) no longer maps to anything.  The top of the current zone (also known as `@`), is *not* covered by a wildcard subdomain entry -  a wildcard subdomain entry only applies to subdomains.

  This is *probably* considered a mistake - unless for some reason you want `mycoolsite.com` not to map to anything, and to be usable only when specifying a subdomain.

Comment: NFSN FAQ has an opinion why you should not use A record for the domain itself. AFAICR they use redirects for naked domains.

Comment: Redirects?  You mean a CNAME?  That's not possible for a domain that has any other records and not a good idea otherwise.  Or do you mean an HTTP redirect?  Those are nothing to do with DNS, bind, or zone files.

Comment: Interesting discussion. Should be separate topic, however NFSN FAQ: It creates noncanonical URLs for your site.
It is less reliable. DNS CNAME records cannot be used in this situation. 
It becomes confusing if you have more than one web site under the domain. (Which site does example.com refer to?)
One name should do one thing. Bare domain names already serve the purpose of organizing the domain, and often they do email duty as well. Web traffic is better kept in its own box. This aids filtering, debugging, and compartmentalizing services.

Comment: Well, assuming this is mainly about wanting to use subdomains per service, like "www" for websites, that's an opinion that the rest of the world is increasingly moving away from, including for example this website (serverfault.com).  Relevant discussion also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109356/www-or-not-www-what-to-choose-as-primary-site-name) and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/domain-www-or-no-www/).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Best practice is a moving target.